# Inverted pedal tones but intervals

Tags: theory, intervals, melody, harmonics, arpeggios

1. What is the correct term when you play melodic intervals in higher pitch than primary melody? As for the rhythmic support for primary melody. If it was pedal tones played that way, it would be called inverted pedal tones, which is rhythmic support, but alternates between consonant and dissonant relationships with melody (or/and harmony).
2. Is there also term for playing arpeggios in higher pitch than primary melody to highlight the fact that arpeggios occurs from higher pitch than melody?

Comment: Descant?.......

Comment: Could it be "outlining the melody"? The term "doubling" is used as in doubling at the octave or doubling at the tenth. There's the term "hetrophony" which is outlining a melody but might not be a common a term (I say because I've used it many times with blank stares, enough to use the term with extreme caution!)

Comment: [Heterophony](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heterophony#:~:text=In%20music%2C%20heterophony%20is%20a,of%20a%20single%20melodic%20line.) from wikipedia.